# Regular Expression check for no string

Tags: regex, string, expression

I want to find from a list of strings (all captial letters) that contains "NAME", but before and after the name I don't want any characters. So I tried this regex "[^A-Z]NAME[^A-Z]. But the string that are like "NAME", or "NAME " can not be matched, I thought the [^A-Z] just check as long they are not in these character, and nothing would also be OK. Did I miss something here?

Chris

Comment: Try this site: http://regexlib.com/
There you can test your regexes and search other peoples regexes

Comment: You must have posted some valid and invalid examples. Well it has been two years....

Answer (score 1):

Try using a word boundry:

```
\bNAME\b
```

Here's a demo: http://regexr.com?33f1d

Comment: Depending on the tool, `\b` may or may not work; an alternative syntax is `\<NAME\>`.